# Limit modal size of a "PopUp" in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, popup, canvas, modal-dialog

I have this :

```
private function tileList_itemClick2(evt:ListEvent):void {
                img = new Image();
                    img.maintainAspectRatio = true;
                    img.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, image_complete);
                    img.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, image_resize);
                    img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, image_click);           

                    img.source = "products/images/" + evt.itemRenderer.data.imgH;
                    img.setStyle("addedEffect", image_addedEffect);
                    img.setStyle("removedEffect", image_removedEffect);
                    PopUpManager.addPopUp(img, myCanvas, true); 
             }
```

Is it possible to limit the modal ( model transparency color ) inside myCanvas ? 
Or even inside other thing than a canvas ?

Comment: What kind of effect are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Something like when you click on one of these products:
http://www.conforama.fr/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ambiance_10001_10051_-2

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make changes to modal transparency.
Inside style sheet put this piece of code.

global
{
      modal-transparency: 0.0;
      modal-transparency-color: white;
      modal-transparency-blur: 0;
}